Should I change my masters supervisor?
I am currently doing a 2-year Master of Science in Aerospace Engineering in a Canadian university under professor A and the research topic is something that I like (scramjet optimization). But recently in a career fair, I was told by people in the National Research Council that the topic I am researching doesn't have a wide career path in Canada and it is almost impossible for a new grad to even get those jobs. I was refered to professor B (who worked in NRC before) from the same school whose research interest (making passenger aircraft more efficient) has more funding and attention from the industry and the government and was told that people like new grads that have done research in these topics. Professor B offered to take me into his team and get me start doing research under his supervision if I agreed to a switch.
Problem is, I have known professor A since my 4th year and when I asked him about research opportunity then, he said he don't have a position for me because of lack of funding. However, after a year, he emailed me and asked me whether I would like a research position without me even asking him about this. And now I have already spent a year in the master program and have finished all the course requirements.
I do want to start working formally (whether in the industry or academic), but I just worry that do the switch now would be like burning a bridge with that professor.
Could I hear your suggestions?

NRC is a national research lab with their own specific funding and work directives. In the past it was an incredible framework for fundamental research, but about 20 years ago it went down very specific applied routes, and frankly much of their scientific output is quite mundane. I know numerous colleagues who left in the 2000-2010 timeframe because of that. The value of your masters degree is to prove that you know topics at a higher level and can complete a short research project. It does not in any way lock you into a career path. Stick with the faculty that will support you.

You should follow a bit altruistic approach and broaden your vision of thinking. Well, whatever you are planning to do (switching in this case) is professionally and academically acceptable but not morally and ethically as you never know Prof. A might have expectations from you and have some unannounced plans for you. He might offer you a PhD position after your masters, who knows. So, whether switching would burn a bridge solely depends on the nature of your professor, as some could be really competitive and egoistic in such matters. If you think your relations are good and he would be open to listen to you with open ears, just arrange a meeting and expressed to him whatever you mention here. Maybe he could give you a better advice. No one can bind you to stay in a research group/lab. In the worst case, you can always go to student counselor and an ombudsman in your department.
